# No guarda nombre de las imagenes

Tags: laravel, angular

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde uso Angular(frontend) y Laravel(backend). Necesito cargar un tramite donde el usuario llena un form, uno de esos campos es un `input='file' multiple` el tramite guarda bien todos los datos de este tramite pero en el campo `img: "[]"` y ahí tendrían que figurar los nombre de las imágenes. Tampoco las guarda en el path que le estoy dando en la api store de laravel. Mi console no me tira ningun error por ende no puedo detectar de donde viene el problema. Y no creo que sea mi backend ya que desde Postman esto funciona perfecto.

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<mat-card class="card-red">
  <img class="logo-img" width="300" src="https://i.ibb.co/Q6tXPHy/img-01.jpg" alt="Logo AMR Salud">
  <mat-card class="card-white">
    <form #formTramite="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveTramite(formTramite)">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="input-date">
        <mat-label>Fecha Tramite</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker3" [value]="date.value" disabled>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker3></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select name="Nro_Documento" placeholder="Grupo Familiar" [(ngModel)]="this.tramitesService.newTramite.Nro_Documento">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let persona of personas" [value]="persona.Nro_Documento">
            {{ persona.Nombre_RSocial }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select name="CodTramite" placeholder="Tramite"  [(ngModel)]="myIdentificador">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let consulta of consultas" [value]="consulta.Identificador">
            {{ consulta.Descripcion }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea name="ObservacionWeb" matInput placeholder="Observacion" [(ngModel)]="this.tramitesService.newTramite.ObservacionWeb"></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
      <input name='img[]' type="file" multiple accept="image/*" (change)="selectFiles($event)">
      <p></p>
      <button mat-button class="btn-enviar" type="submit" (click)="uploadFiles()">Enviar</button>
    </form>
    </mat-card>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
    selectFiles(event){
        this.progressInfos = [];
    
        const files = event.target.files;
        let isImage = true;
    
        for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
          if(files.item(i).type.match('image.*')){
            continue;
          }else{
            isImage = false;
            alert('Formato invalido!');
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isImage) {
          this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
          console.log('ok')
        }else{
          this.selectedFiles = undefined;
          event.srcElement.percentage = null;
        }
      }


    upload(idx, file) {
        this.progressInfos[idx] = { value: 0, fileName: file.name };
      
        this.tramitesService.upload(file).subscribe(
          event => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              this.progressInfos[idx].percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              this.fileInfos = this.tramitesService.getFiles();
            }
          },
          err => {
            this.progressInfos[idx].percentage = 0;
            this.message = 'Could not upload the file:' + file.name;
          });
      }


uploadFiles() {
    this.message = '';
  
    for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      this.upload(i, this.selectedFiles[i]);
      console.log(this.selectedFiles);
    }
  }
```

services.ts

```
upload(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
    const URL_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tramites';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('img', file)

    const request = new HttpRequest('POST',URL_ENDPOINT, formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'multipart/form-data',
      }),
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });
    return this.http.request(request);
  }

  getFiles(): Observable<any> {
    const URL_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tramites'
    return this.http.get(URL_ENDPOINT);
  }
```

Controller.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $values = $request->except('img');
        $data = $request->only('img');
        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            foreach($request->file('img') as $image){
                $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move('storage\img', $name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
        }
        
        $tramite = new Tramite;
        $tramite = Tramite::create($values);
        $tramite->img = json_encode($data);
        $tramite->save();

        return response()->json($tramite, 201);

    }
```

Comment: que haces en onSaveTramite, y según entiendo tienes un evento en el botón submit, que genera la carga de la imagen, y el de el submit que se ejecutara cuando termine el evento del botón, pero si tu llamada a cargar la imagen es asíncrona, entonces no terminara de cargar la imagen, para cuando envías el formulario,  y nunca veo que asignes un nombre de archivo cuando recibes la respuesta de tu imagen.

Comment: Yo enviaría el evento cargar imágenes, dentro de tu submit, que se ejecute y cuando tengas una respuesta, asignar ese valor a alguna variable y entonces si realizas la carga de tu formulario.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea en onSaveTramite tengo lo siguiente
`onSaveTramite(tramiteForm: NgForm): void {
    let sec = this.myIdentificador.split('-')[1];
    let cod = this.myIdentificador.split('-')[0];
    let tram = this.ultTramite;
    tramiteForm.value.NroTramite = Number(tram)+1;
    tramiteForm.value.SectorDer  = Number(sec);
    tramiteForm.value.CodTramite = Number(cod);
    this.tramitesService.saveTramite(tramiteForm.value).subscribe(tramites => console.log(tramites));
  }`